# How can I show an image from link in android push notification?

Tags: php, android, ios

I have to show an image from [demo link](http://demo.ivdisplays.net//broadcast//school_admin//notification_images//thumbnail//thumb_1490003439class%20routing.png)

This is the data payload data

```
{"registration_ids":["","","","","","","","e132domchYE:APA91bEyVcuR8Qpl46
jNfs0CTg4gizFqUDze06wzdzaCsHOI0KwRqcV-Ml5ZlkWJF0b44pCJMWJT0Uk7ApvPoh8pOOtRO0xQWlnj9
Sa8Aii15tSR_U8KB4Dr"],"data":{"title":"50%+discount+sale","message":"grab+now",
"image":"http:\/\/demo.ivdisplays.net\/broadcast\/school_admin\/notification
_images\/thumbnail\/thumb_1490003439class routing.png"}}
```

I have to show the image in the following link in push notification just like an e-commerce app.

Comment: may be this link will help you http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this, will work

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(url);

                            NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle s = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap);
                            s.setSummaryText("Image");
                            nBuilder.setStyle(s);
                          nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

> **Create Method getBitmapFromURL**

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

mNotificationManager.notify(0, nBuilder.build());
```

Comment: How can I fetch the image link from json?

Comment: best and simple, much more convenient then Glide option